# why i am getting this error : - Cannot destructure property 'basename' of 'react__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.useContext(...)' as it is null

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, tailwind-css

why i am getting this error : - Cannot destructure property 'basename' of 'react__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.useContext(...)' as it is null ?

```
import Header from "./components/Header";
import Body from "./components/Body";
import store from "./utils/store";
import MainContainer from "./components/MainContainer";
import WatchPage from "./components/WatchPage";
import SearchedVdoContainer from "./components/SearchedVdoContainer";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { RouterProvider, createBrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";

function App() {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <Header />
      <RouterProvider router={appRouter} />
    </Provider>
  );
}
const appRouter = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: "/",
    element: <Body />,
    children: [
      {
        path: "/",
        element: <MainContainer />,
      },
      {
        path: "/watch",
        element: <WatchPage />,
      },
      {
        path: "/results",
        element: <SearchedVdoContainer />
      }
    ],
  },
]);

export default App;
//and error is coming from below code

import React from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
const SearchResult = ({ Searchresult }) => {
 
  return (
    <div      
      className="px-4 py-1 flex items-center  gap-4 rounded-xl cursor-pointer transition duration-300 hover:bg-gray-300"
    >
      <i className="fa-sharp fa-solid fa-magnifying-glass  text-gray-500 cursor-pointer"></i>
      <Link to={`/results`}>
      <span>{Searchresult}</span>
      </Link>
    </div>
  );
};

export default SearchResult;
```

onclick of this
<span>{Searchresult}</span>
I should go /results page but it is throwing above error

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74168742/how-to-template-jsx-with-createbrowserrouter